# Calcular distancia entre mi ubicación y un marcador seleccionado en google maps android

Tags: google-maps

Hola deseo calcular la distancia entre mi ubicación y un marcador seleccionado del mapa, estoy utilizando esta fórmula pero el problema radica en que no puedo obtener mi ubicación, el resultado lo trato de mostrar en un textview pero aparece en blanco: el código es el siguiente:

```
        private String lo;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc ) {
    Double lati = loc.getLatitude();
    Double loni = loc.getLongitude();

    LatLng position = marker.getPosition();


    double distance = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(new LatLng(loni, lati), new LatLng(position.latitude,position.longitude));
    lo = Double.toString(distance);



}
```

se supone que en el primer segmento obtengo mi mi ubicación y la almaceno en variables por latitud y longitud, luego obtengo las ubicación del marcador que selecciono y luego utilizo la la utilidad de Google para calcular la distancia entre mi ubicación y el marcador que selecciono... Pero no sucede nada todo compila bien pero al momento de ejecutar ese textview sale en blanco, no muestra nada

Comment: Hola Xavier. Has hecho algun tipo de log o usado el debugger para ver qué esta sucediendo? (valores en las variables, resultados de funciones ...). y `marker` donde lo inicializas? Un saludo

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, estuve checando con un toast y me envia un resultado nulo, ya he probado varias cosas pero no logro hacer que funcione, el marker es el que recoge los valores de ese marcador valga la redundancia ya que se usa en el Onmapready y alli esta el valor LatLng position = marker. Getposition()